# Completely remove mysql from Linux

Tags: linux, mysql, arch-linux, pacman

I am trying to remove Mysql completely from my system with the command but always getting not found error

```
[name@archserver]$ sudo pacman -R mysql
error: target not found: mysql
[name@archserver]$ sudo pacman -R mysqld 
error: target not found: mysqld
```

When I try to find out where is MySql,

```
[name@archserver]$ whereis mysql
mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /etc/mysql /usr/include/mysql /usr/share/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
```

How can I remove Mysql from my system?

Comment: Find your installed packages with `pacman -Ss mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

`pacman -Ql mysql | less` will give you a list of files installed by the package. 
To uninstall mysql and all its dependencies that are not needed by any other packages try `sudo pacman -Rns mysql`.

mysqld is a daemon though. i suggest you take a look at the links below.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Daemons

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman